# Android: Changing the icon in an ArrayList

Tags: android, opengl-es

Android: OpenGL ES: I'm displaying some STL files (meshes). Some are partial forms (picture part of an egg shell) where, as you rotate them, you can see either the front of the triangles (outside) or the back of the triangles (inside). I want to see both sides of this shape but if I enable culling I can't see the inside because the triangles are facing away from me so they are culled.

I could switch off culling, but on big meshes that's a big performance hit during rotates. Is there any other way of making the back of triangles visible without disabling culling? Or are these options mutually exclusive?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Baz

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question at all, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Culling literally means "don't show this side."  So yeah, mutually exclusive.

An alternative would be to keep culling on, and add front-facing polys to your meshes in the areas which look like the "inner" part of the model.

Comment: I suspected as much. I also tried just doubling the drawarrays - once with frontface CCW and once CW so there's a mirror image of the open mesh back to back with it, but of course there's a big performance hit there too :/ thanks anyway.